# Android AlarmManager: how to use it to STOP an Activity

Tags: android, alarmmanager

In my App I use an AlarmManager to start an Activty at a certain days of the week and at a certain hour.

So I have an AlarmManager that an MON, TUE, WED.. at 12:00 fires off an Activity...

Now, the point is that I need to stop the same activity at a precise time (again using the AlarmManager if it is possible).

Please how do I achieve that: AlarmManager to STOP an Activity?

Comment: If you need to stop it I can assume that is running, right? If its running you could make the Second alarm to change a value in that activity and when that value is set the activity call `finish();`

Comment: The same way you START the activity, why don't you just do finish() on that activity ?

Comment: Why Activity? This is not a good pattern. You should use Service.

Comment: Thanks to all, are all very useful answers!!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can register a broadcastReceiver in that activity. if you wanna stop it, send a broadcast notification to that Activity, and trigger relevant callback function to finish the activity.

Answer (score 1):

As Pankaj said use services and u can unregister the broadcast reciever

```
public void stopService() {
    Log.d("TAG", "CancelAlarm Start");
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, PullNotification.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent
            .getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(sender);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much ! Please could you explain to me why do you think that using a Service for my purpose would be a better idea ? Thank you again !!!! Lisa

Comment: Since u are doing background process service suits better than invoking the activity.